# Is there a simple page showing a visual comparison of the different pre-made R color scales available?

Tags: r, plot, color-mapping

Often when I am quickly doing some plots to get a feel for my data, I don't wish to agonize exactly what colors my color map should have. I just want something "good enough", that I can call with a single short command, and move on.

On [this page](http://www.r-bloggers.com/color-palettes-in-r/), I found some basic color palettes:

- `rainbow(n)`
- `heat.colors(n)`
- `terrain.colors(n)`
- `topo.colors(n)`
- `cm.colors(n)`

This is sort of what I want, except there isn't enough of it. terrain and topo are specialized for maps, rainbow is notoriously bad, cm is for data roughly centered around 0, and heat doesn't look good for data spanning [0, 1].

Is there more colormaps? Is there a site or document somewhere showing a list of all the colormaps from different packages so I can just look through it and pick whichever one looks best?

Comment: I don't know such webpage. But you can visualize color palettes from package `RColorBrewer` using the function `display.brewer.all()` from this package.

Comment: That's very nice! Pretty close to what I was looking for.

Comment: See http://colorbrewer2.org/

Answer (score 0):

How are you plotting your graphs?

I use `ggplot2` a large amount, and the colour keys on there are pretty good as a default. Further there are very good tools for mapping variables by colour available, and it works well with both `RColourBrewer`, `Scales`, and `ggthemes`

Information onf ggplot2 colours: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/
More information on ggthemes: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggthemes/vignettes/ggthemes.html

Comment: I was using `heatmap` for this, but I think `heatmap` and `ggplot` both use the same color scale.